# Passing 2D ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Can someone show me how to set up getters and setters for this 2D ArrayList?

```
public class PureRatings {
private List<List<Integer>> pureRatingsList;
```

I'm not sure if this part is right...

```
public PureRatings() throws IOException {
    pureRatingsList = parseRatingsFile();
}
```

Here is the code for the rest of the 2D ArrayList, I didn't know if I should include it or not...

```
public static List<List<Integer>> parseRatingsFile() throws IOException {
    List<List<Integer>> pureRatings = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Ratings.txt"));
    String ratingsLine = null;
    while ((ratingsLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        pureRatings.add(parseRatingsLine(ratingsLine));
    }
    in.close();

    return pureRatings;
}

public static List<Integer> parseRatingsLine(String ratingsLine) throws IOException {
    List<Integer> ratings = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (ratingsLine == null) {
        return ratings;
    }

    String[] ratingsStrArr = ratingsLine.split(" ");
    try {
        for (final String ratingStr : ratingsStrArr) {
            ratings.add(Integer.parseInt(ratingStr));

        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return ratings;
}
```

}

Comment: The constructor looks fine. Have you tried executing it?

Comment: Was just about to finish the main class to test it but I was having trouble passing this list to it.

Comment: @TedHopp I ran the file to print out the elements and it worked ( though not the way I thought it would). I ran it again without anything inside the constructor and it also worked. I think I am misunderstanding the purpose of the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void setPureRatingsList(List<List<Integer>> lst)
{
  pureRatingsList = lst;
}

public List<List<Integer>> getPureRatingsList()
{
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(pureRatingsList);
}
```

Comment: @Marcos I believe yes. Compile your program. Compiler will show errors if you are not specifying it correct.

Comment: Is the Collections.unmodifiableList() method necessary? Won't that make it so I can' change the list?

Comment: @Marcos you can remove it but that prevents concurrency related issues. For now just remove it

Comment: PureRatings pureRatings = new PureRatings();
        List<List<Integer>> pureRatingsList = pureRatings.parseRatingsFile();
I had to write that to be able to pass it. I think I don't understand the constructor...

Answer (score 2):

You would get an entry like this:

```
pureRatingsList.get(line).get(column);
```

You would set an entry like this:

```
pureRatings.get(line).set(column, newValue);
```

Comment: That would be to change values right? I have another class that does that...all I need to do right now is to pass this 2D arraylist to that class or else that other class is useless, haha...thanks though...

Comment: as a good practice, it would be useful to check whether `pureRatings` is not `null` and has elements up to `line`, etc.